# form submission ignores jquery dialog buttons and continue to submit

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the following form code and the javascript code as shown  below. Problem is when the execution reaches `validateDialogForm()`, a jquery diaog is shown if some conditions are satisfied. And I do see the diaog for few seconds but it won't stay there and form just keeps on submitting. I want to form to halt for sometime and submit only when user hits `save` button. I have tried putting `return false;` just before the end of `validateDialogForm()` function so that stops the form from submitting but then when I hit the save button of the dialog, it won't move forward with submitting the form and just stays as it is. What am I doing wrong here? Current state of below code is that the form will continue to submit regardless of jquery dialog. (Lot of irrelevant code has been removed for clarity)

```js
$('#checklist_dialog').hide();

function validateDialogForm() {

  $('#checklist_dialog').show();
  var isConfirmed = false;

  //STEP:1 Check if option B is selected.
  var selectedVal = "";
  var selected = $("input[type='radio'][name='sampleChoice']:checked");

  if (selected.length > 0) {
    selectedVal = selected.val();
    console.log("Selected Option is " + selectedVal);
  }

  if (selectedVal === "choiceB") {
    if ($("#choiceBstatus").val() === "true") {
      //show the dialog box
      $('#checklist_dialog').dialog({
        modal: true,
        maxWidth: 600,
        maxHeight: 500,
        width: 600,
        height: 500,
        overlay: {
          opacity: 0.7,
          background: "black"
        },
        buttons: {
          "SAVE": function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            alert("Inside SAVE button which is clicked");
            $("#choiceBstatus").val("false");
            //isConfirmed = true;

            return true;
          },
          "CANCEL": function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            alert("You must complete / save the checklist before saving your form!");
            // return false;

          }
        }
      });
      /* e.preventDefault();
                            return false; */
    } //end of  if($("#choiceBstatus").val() == true ){

    if ($("#choiceBstatus").val() === "false") {
      // return true;
    }
  } //end of  if(selectedVal === "choiceB"){

  //return false;               

  /* if(isConfirmed){
    
    return true;
  }         
  else {
    return false;
  }
   */
}
```

```html
<form id="orderForm" action="/mywebsite/order.htm" method="POST" onsubmit="return (validateOrderForm(this) && validateDialogForm())">
  <input id="choiceBstatus" name="choiceBstatus" type="hidden" value="true">
  <div id="ownerDisplayFields" style="visibility: visible;">
    <table class="noPrint">
      //some divs

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="pManualTitle" style="display: block">
    <table class="noPrint">
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="checklist_dialog" title="New Title" style="display: none;">

    <p>Checklist 1 goes here</p>
    <p>Checklist 2 goes here </p>


  </div>

  <table class="noPrint">
    <tbody>
      <tr>

        <td align="center"><br>
          <input class="button" type="submit" name="save" value="Save"> - <input class="button" type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel" onclick="bCancel = true;">


        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why do you call both `onsubmit="return (validateOrderForm(this) && validateDialogForm())"` ?

Comment: Because `validateOrderForm(this)` is used for many other forms and I want to have `validateDialogForm()` related checks only for this form.

Comment: `dialog()` is asynchronous, it doesn't wait for the user to answer the dialogue. And the return values from the button functions aren't used for anything.

Comment: If you want form submission to depend on the dialogue answer, you need to disable the default submission and call `form.submit()` in the `SAVE` button function.

Comment: By `disable default submission`, do i need to change `type=submit`  in `<input class="button" type="submit" name="save" value="Save">` to `type=button` and then use `form.submit()` ? Same for `cancel` button as well?

Comment: That would also work, you can certainly do it that way too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you need to prevent the form from submitting when the dialog shows since the dialog will not block the UI. It will continue to submit unless you stop it. After you press the button in the dialog, then you can submit the form for real.

The tricky part now is that when you submit the form for real that will also trigger the `onsubmit` functions again! A good way to do this is to set a flag.  See the below pseudo-code that should basically do what you want

```html
<form id="orderForm"
      action="/mywebsite/order.htm"
      method="POST"
      onsubmit="return (validateOrderForm(this) && validateDialogForm(this))">
...
```

```js
let real_form_submit = false;

function validateDialogForm(theForm){
  if(!real_form_submit) {
    $('#checklist_dialog').dialog({
      ...
      buttons: {
        "SAVE": function() {
          $(this).dialog('close');
          real_form_submit = true;
          theForm.submit()
        },
        "CANCEL": function() {
          $(this).dialog('close');
        }
      }
    });
  }

  return real_form_submit;
}
```